# how to pick only next 4 days interval from start date in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

Im not sure if my question is explaining what i need to do..i have 2 datepicker field start and end and in the start date field  only Monday can be selected and on the end date only Friday can be selected every other days are disabled...so what i need is if i select monday then i need to be able to select  the coming Friday and disable all other dates so they can select just and only 4 days not more then that or less then that..

here is my code...any help would be really appreciated..

```
                $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    minDate: '+0',
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate);

                    },
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var day = date.getDay();
                        return [(day != 0 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day != 6)];
                    }
                });
                $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                    },
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var day = date.getDay();
                        return [(day != 0 && day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4  && day != 6)];
                    }
                });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/96Lbf/ you can desable the to date here.

Comment: that worked for me actually..thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help you :). Mark as correct if its helpful to you.